# How to toggle a comment in kdevelop?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kdevelop

Kdevelop has separate commands for commenting (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) and uncommenting (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>).

Is there a way of using a single shortcut to toggle both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use *Settings->Configure Shortcuts* and enter `comment` in the search box.

You will see a line *Toggle Comment*, which you can assign a keyboard shortcut.

In this same list of results you'll see *Comment* and *Uncomment* which you may like to unassign bindings from.

Comment: When I use this "toggle comment" shortcut, my Kdevelop inserts the xml style comment `<!-- -->`, even if I'm working in a C++ file. But the "comment/uncomment" shortcut gives the desired `/* */`. Where can I config this setting?

Answer (score 3):

In my version of kdevelop / kate (v. 4.6.0 / 3.13.3 using KDE 4.13.3, from Ubuntu 14.04) there are two different entries in `Settings / Configure Shortcuts...` and they are both located under Kate Part grouping:

- The first one is spelled 'Toggle comment' and always tries to use the
  HTML/XML style comments `<!-- -->`;
- The second one, spelled 'Toggle
  Comment' has a context specific behavior, and it is probably what you
  would like to assign the shortcut to.

Maybe it would be a good idea to request some developers to assign it by default to `Ctrl + /`, which is somewhat the most used one to the best of my knowledge.